# Brackets-Why IntersectionObserver is not responding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in web development, and I'm using Brackets.
Recently I have come across several problems related to javascript.
One of them is that I'm trying to lazy load a div with text inside.
All I get as result is a blank page.

In addition, as you can see in js code, I tried to add an "alert" inside the IntersectionObserver function, and surprisingly, no massage poped-up.

**Code:**

```js
/*eslint-env es6*/
/*eslint-env browser*/
   
const faders = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-in");
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-in");

const appearOptions = {
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -250px 0px"
};


const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  appearOnScroll
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
      alert("error");
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("appear");
      appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
},
appearOptions);

faders.forEach(fader => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});

sliders.forEach(slider => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(slider);
});
```

```css
.FadeIn{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in;
}
.FadeIn.appear{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="FadeIn">
        <h4> Some text .. </h4>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?, Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html and css the class is called **FadeIn**, while in Javascript it's called **fade-in**. It seems to work if you fix that:

```js
const faders = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-in");
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-in");

const appearOptions = {
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -250px 0px"
};


const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  appearOnScroll
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.add("appear");
      appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
},
appearOptions);

faders.forEach(fader => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});

sliders.forEach(slider => {
  appearOnScroll.observe(slider);
});
```

```css
.fade-in{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in;
}
.fade-in.appear{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in">
  <h4> Some text .. </h4>
</div>
```